# Group e-mail login data by domain using regex [Java]

Tags: java

I have a list of e-mails which looks something like this:

```
james; james@gmail.com
george; george@gmail.com
alex; alex@yahoo.com
anthony; anthony@yahoo.com
mike; mike@outlook.com
```

I need to organize them like this:

```
james,george - gmail.com
alex,anthony - yahoo.com
mike - outlook.com
```

How do I do this in Java using regex without using any container classes and streams?

Comment: Are the `*`s part of your input data and expected output?

Comment: Also, is there a predefined list of possible domains?

Comment: No, domains can be totally random, and those '*'s are not a part of the input data

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to have Map to store list of names for each domain. You can use split method on string like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String [] emails = {
            "james; james@gmail.com",
            "george; george@gmail.com",
            "alex; alex@yahoo.com",
            "anthony; anthony@yahoo.com",
            "mike; mike@outlook.com"};
    
    Map<String,List<String>> domains = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> names = null;
    
    for(String entry : emails) {
        String[] data = entry.split(";|@");
        if(domains.containsKey(data[2])){
            names = domains.get(data[2]);
        } else {
            names = new ArrayList<>();
            domains.put(data[2], names);
        }
        names.add(data[0]);
    }
    
    for(String key : domains.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(domains.get(key) + " - " + key);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[mike] - outlook.com
[james, george] - gmail.com
[alex, anthony] - yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how close it is to what you intended, but I gave it a shot:

```
String [] emails = {
        "james; james@gmail.com",
        "george; george@gmail.com",
        "alex; alex@yahoo.com",
        "anthony; anthony@yahoo.com",
        "mike; mike@outlook.com"};

Map<String, String> mailMap = new HashMap<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" (.+)@(.+)");

for (String string : emails) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    if (m.find( )) {
        String name = m.group(1);
        String mailProvider = m.group(2);
        
        if (mailMap.containsKey(mailProvider)) {
            String oldValue = mailMap.get(mailProvider);
            mailMap.put(mailProvider, oldValue + "," + name);
        } else {
            mailMap.put(mailProvider, name);
        }
        
     } else {
        System.out.println("String did match expected format");
     }
}

for (String mailProvider : mailMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(mailMap.get(mailProvider) + " - " + mailProvider);
}
```

Comment: Pattern will not find `james; james1969@gmail.com` and if it did, above code will pick `james1969` as name and not `james`.

Comment: @onkarruikar Thank you for the correction, I'll edit it in! Though the question wasn't clear on whether it needed james or james1969.